# suggestions for Choosing a data structure for a friendship network

Tags: python, data-structures

I have to implement a program which analyzes friendship. There will be a text file which will contain group of friends.so when user input a name from the group, the program shows who are this person's friends.
For example, the text file contains,
Erina;Mira; Kyla;
If user inputs Mira it will show other person as her friends..
I need to store the text file data in a data structure.. So what kind of data structure will be suitable for this in python? Should I go for a dictionary??
( The question asks for nested data structure)

Comment: Using a dict should be fine and simple.

Comment: It depends of the level of your course. I am not sure a list of dicts qualifies as a nested data structure. May be you would better go for a graph data structure, for example see https://python.plainenglish.io/data-structure-in-python-graph-8fb3dbc0ddf

Comment: @hpchavaz I actually haven't studied graph yet in this course.. dictionary,sets, tuple,lists have been contents till now.. that's why I was asking if dictionary will be a good idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a dictionary would be your best bet. You could store the name of the person as the key and the a list of friends as the value. You can then append friends to the list like this:

```
friends_dict = dict()
friends_dict['john'] = []
friends_dict['john'].append("lisa")
print(friends_dict)
$ {'john':['lisa']}
```

Comment: so you are suggesting a list within a dictionary? right?